# Python giving invalid syntaxerror that is unidentifiable

Tags: python, compiler-errors, syntax-error

So I have my script to do a function.

The code for the function is:

```
def full_description(item_name):
    try:
        all_at_once(item_name)
        get_dates(item_name)
        get_journal(item_name)
    except(KeyboardInterrupt):
        print('User quit the program.')
        raise KeyboardInterrupt
    except:
        print('There was an error and the current item has been skipped.')
    try:
        descriptions['es']
        try:
            journal_label
            print(journal_label)
            journal_exists = 1
        except(KeyError):
                nothing = 'no journal'
        except(KeyboardInterrupt):
            print('User quit the program.')
            raise KeyboardInterrupt
        except:
            print('There was an error and the current item has been skipped.')
        try:
            date
            print(date)
            date_exists = 1
        except(KeyError):
            nothing = 'no date'
        except(KeyboardInterrupt):
            print('User quit the program.')
            raise KeyboardInterrupt
        except:
            print('There was an error and the current item has been skipped.')
        if journal_exists==1:
            descriptions['es'] = descriptions['es'] + 'en' + journal_label
            if date_exists==1:
                descriptions['es'] = descriptions['es'] + 'en' + journal_label + 'a' + date
            elif date_exists==1:
                descriptions['es'] = descriptions['es'] + 'a' + date
            else:
                descriptions['es'] = descriptions['es']
        except(KeyError):
            nothing = 'there is no spanish'
        except(KeyboardInterrupt):
            print('User quit the program.')
            raise KeyboardInterrupt
        except:
            print('There was an error and the current item has been skipped.')
```

However, for the randomest reason ever, python is throwing a syntax error. I get this error every time I try to run a script.

```
  File "~\add_descriptions.py", line 166
    if journal_exists==1:
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I cannot find the incorrect syntax, and I checked the above line and found that it was completely correct.

What is my syntax error?

Comment: But you bind an `except` (a few lines lower) with an `if` statement?

Comment: indentation is off i think

Comment: Shouldn't you indent it a level deeper? Or use a new `try`?

Comment: I suspect the indentation in your post doesn't match the indentation in the file you ran. If everything looks fine, check for mixed tabs and spaces.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you that was the problem

Comment: @frozen the statement was indented too deep

Comment: (This code makes very little sense, by the way. It's trying to catch KeyErrors in places that couldn't possibly have any, using bare `except`s that will only hide bugs, attempting (incorrectly) to check for possibly-defined variables only to create *more* possibly-defined variables and rendering the check useless, etc.)

Comment: @user2357112 The problem is that now that there are so many excepts I can't find the main ones!

Comment: @PokestarFan I suggest you to find an IDE to work with, you save a lot of time avoiding to solve these little issues.

Comment: @Bit I use [Atom](https://www.atom.io), but what IDE's do you recommend?

Comment: @PokestarFan I personally use PyCharm.